# Get JSON from URL via Curl with https returns Null

Tags: php, json, curl

Hi i'm trying to get the data from a JSON file from a url using Curl and PHP with this code:

```
<?php
    //  Initiate curl
    $url = "https://panel.virtualcenter360.es/home/api/getdatasample?dateIni=1376524800&dateEnd=1381795200";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    $res = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($result));

    var_dump(json_decode($res, true));

        switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I'm getting the No errors message, but a NULL result. What do you think that could be the problem?

Maybe I need to configure some parameters from Curl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to work with curl you have to do this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
>   FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is fetch some json info, I'd suggest you use `file_get_contents()` instead of the cURL functions.

Comment: I have also tried with file_get_contents() like: $result = file_get_contents('https://panel.virtualcenter360.es/home/api/getdatasample?dateIni=1376524800&dateEnd=1381795200'); var_dump(json_decode($result, true));  But I'm getting errors.

Comment: `$result = file_get_contents('https://panel.virtualcenter360.es/home/api/getdatasample?dateIni=1376524800&dateEnd=1381795200'); 
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));` works fine for me. I suggest you try this with [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for chrome or some other tool to test.

Comment: Hi i have tried with file_gets_contents in a Online server and It works. I think the problem it's when tried from a wamp localhost server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter application/libraries folder

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output)); //Comment line no. 267 of REST_Controller.php
```